# FN keys trigger normal F keys

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04, my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work, but when I press them system/apps react to the function keys bindings too e.g. if I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to lower the volume my browser goes full screen... can I change this behaviour in any way?

Comment: what happens if you press only `F11`

Comment: system reacts to that binding i.e. in this case the browser goes full screen. The problem is that adding FN key does not block other keyboard bindings...

Comment: Please run the command `xev` and see what happens when you press Fn-F11 and Fn.

Comment: It's seems that something in the updates corrected this behaviour. Sorry fo the bother.